# mysqli getting warning in php for updateing the data

Tags: php, mysqli

```
function update($data, $table, $id)
{
    global $conid;
    //echo $id;
        /*Assuming array keys are = to database fileds*/
        if (count($data) > 0) {
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

                $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($value); // this is line shows a warning
                $value = "'$value'";
                $updates[] = "$key = $value";
            }
        }
        $implodeArray = implode(', ', $updates);
        $sql = ("UPDATE $table  SET $implodeArray WHERE id=$id");
        mysqli_query($conid, $sql);


}
```

This is update code for all forms but it gives a warning. warning shows only in that line other works perfectly i didn't find why this happen..

Comment: What's the warning message?

Comment: Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters

Answer (score 0):

Since your using **mysqli_*** function then you have to include your connection to database into [mysqli_real_escape](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) function :

You need to change

```
$value = mysqli_real_escape_string($value);
```

to

```
$value = mysqli_real_escape_string($conid, $value);
```

Comment: ok. Thank you.................

Comment: You’re welcome, If it helped you, please [upvote and accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) Happy Coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

**mysql**

```
 $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($value);
```

**mysqli**  //in mysqli 2 perameter needed as `connection object` and `string data`

```
 $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($conid,$value);//connection object
```